# Javascript: Can't get an on-click event to search through an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

If a user clicks on:

```
<a href="hello.php" id="hello_homepage">hello</a>
```

the jQuery on the page should pick up this on click event:

```
$('hello_homepage').on('click', function()
    { ga('send', 'event', 'home page', 'Click', 'some dude clicked on the hello link');     }
);
```

That's easy.

However I have around 200 different link ID's, so want to put them in one JS/jQuery array to optimise this. How can I do the following:

```
$('Analytic_Event.id').on('click', function()
    { ga('send', 'event', 'Analytic_Event.cat', 'Click', 'Analytic_Event.label'); }
);

var Analytic_Event = [
        // Home Page
        {id : "hello_homepage", cat: "Home Page", label: "some dude clicked on the hello link"},
        {id : "goodbye_homepage", cat: "Home Page", label: "some dude clicked on the goodbye link"},
        {id : "ciao_homepage", cat: "Home Page", label: "some dude clicked on the ciao link"},

        ]
```

Any help much appreciated as I'm a little lost how this works.

Cheers

Comment: You meant to write `$('#hello_homepage')`, right ?

Comment: Actually, your code is full of errors, wrong selectors etc ...

Comment: That's what only half learning a host of languages has provided me with, so I do apologise for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim's answer would be the right way to go unless for any reason you can't modify that code, otherwise:

```
$.each(Analytic_Event, function(key, item) {
   // do whatever with item 
});
```

if you really have to anyways

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jim and for your help David, that idea works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your links and wire the onclick to the class.

```
<a href="hello.php" class="ga" id="hello_homepage">hello</a>
<a href="page1.php" class="ga" id="page1">page1</a>
<a href="goodbye.php" class="ga" id="goodbye_homepage">good bye</a>
```

Use some of the link attributes when you send the event to ga.

```
$('.ga').on('click', function() {
    var linkID = $(this).attr("id");

    ga('send', 'event', linkID , 'Click', 'some dude clicked on the ' + linkID + ' link');     }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, Jim.

So just to be clear, I have multiple items in each array that need to be placed into the:

    ga('send', 'event', linkID , 'Click', 'some dude clicked on the ' + linkID + ' link');

So how should the array syntax look for me to pull in those items into the above on click event function, as there may be more and more array items added per unique array.

Cheers

Comment: @Ryan: my solution didn't use the "array" approach, rather I simply use the attributes of the links to log the event with ga (this is how I do it with my websites).  See David Carpenter's answer for a solution that uses the array.

Comment: @Ryan: I basically have a generic function (like the $('.ga').on('click'... in my answer), and then wire it up to any event link I want Google Analytics to track.